# SQL Server : retrieving stored procedure errors and use them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to get the error that I get from a different stored procedure.

For example a user is trying to add a duplicate product id into a table; this will fail and it will throw a duplicate key error. If a user tries to insert `NULL`, it will also fail .

How can I get those errors and identify them so I can use the error to display a different error message? I know I can put the error on an output parameter but I don't know how to identify which error occurred .

Using SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TRY CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) blocks to handle the errors. Generally, you can use the following template:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH; 

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END;

   -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR

END CATCH;
```

If you are not using `TRANSACTION`, it will looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRY

    -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH; 

   -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR

END CATCH;
```

In the `CATCH` block, you can get errors details using some built-in functions. For example:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;  
GO
```

Then, based on this details you can do something (log an error, do nothing, save the error details in a variable and pass them to outer routine, generate the same error using [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or again using `THROW`- generate some your custom `THROW 51000, 'My Custom error message.', 1;`.